# Visual Studio WPF generating identical conflicting partial class files

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, user-controls, code-behind

I have custom usercontrols in a WPF project. My solution will no longer compile. When I try to build/ including after a clean/rebuild (even after deleting the bin and obj folders) VS generates two code files: control.g.vb and control.g.i.vb

The code in these files contains partial classes connected to the codebehind class, and the two generated files are identical. Visual studio then determines that they conflict with each other, causing compile errors such as "Public Sub InitializeComponent() has multiple definitions with identical signatures" which it does, one in control.g.vb and one in control.g.i.vb

What is happening, how did it happen, and how can I fix it?

I have searched all the relevant keywords I can think of on google, SO, and MSDN. The most relevant advice I have found involved deleting the bin and obj files and doing a clean and rebuild, which I have tried.

Example errors
Error       'Public Sub System_Windows_Markup_IComponentConnector_Connect(connectionId As Integer, target As Object)' has multiple definitions with identical signatures.   {solution file path}\obj\x86\Debug\Controls\user controls{folder}{control}.g.i.vb {project}

Comment: Those files are always generated.  If I were to bet, I'd say you changed the namespace for one or both of your user controls but you didn't do it correctly.  If you did, I'd suggest copying both the XAML and cs files for these controls to a location outside of your solution, creating new versions in the locations you want them to exist, and then copy the bare minimum from each of the original files into their new versions.  That means only copying out the class definitions (no namespaces!), and everything excluding the root element in your XAML.  Add back only those attributes needed to

Comment: get it to compile.  If that doesn't work, create a new solution, copy one of your user controls over, then edit everything out that you can while still reproducing the problem.  Once you've paired it down to a minimal example, post that in an [edit].

Comment: As far as I'm aware, I haven't touched the namespace at all. I didn't try to move them to a new location or anything.

In addition, I only have control over a small part of one project in this solution. If I try to check out more than that for editing it'll cause problems for other developers on the project.

Comment: There isn't enough info here to answer, unfortunately.  Exact error messages (please don't take screenshots!) would help.  Code would help (that's why I suggested reproing and pairing down).

Comment: I'll work on repro and paring it down. In the meantime, see edit for an example the actual errors I'm getting and please let me know if there's more information I can provide that would be helpful.

Comment: It was a naming problem. Xaml files were referring to classes other than their own code-behind files, and the classes in code-behind files were named differently from the file name. Once those were all corrected the issue was fixed.

I can only assume I did this at some point.

Thank you for your help. If you post an answer I will mark the question answered.

Comment: I hope the next poor idiot who does the same thing finds this answer relatively quickly

Comment: Ah, renaming can cause the exact same issue as moving.  I Should have added that possibility.  Anyhow, add an answer below with details about what you did and how you fixed it and you can close this out.  I need to find a nice canonical question about this (relatively common) problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: Be very careful when renaming files in Visual Studio.

I had renamed some files and classes, but didn't catch all the references to them. I had controls that were pointing to classes that were named things other than their own code-behind files, and classes that were named differently from the files they were in. No wonder Visual Studio got confused.